# How do I force wget to use a proxy server without modifying system files?

Tags: command-line, proxy, wget

I'd like to know an equivalent to wget enabling me to set the proxy while calling the command (like `wget --proxy=$http_proxy`).

Any ideas ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a proxy on the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47379/how-to-use-a-proxy-on-the-command-line)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211705/how-to-set-proxy-for-wget

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Without modifying your system files at `/etc/wgetrc` you could create a file at your home directory `~/.wgetrc`. It will enable you to modify wget settings locally at user level. Now write the following at `~/.wgetrc` to use wget behind a proxy server:

```
use_proxy = on
http_proxy =  http://username:password@proxy.server.address:port/
https_proxy =  http://username:password@proxy.server.address:port/
ftp_proxy =  http://username:password@proxy.server.address:port/
```

If you do not have proxy username and password just write the proxy-address and port everywhere like,

```
http_proxy =  http://proxy.server.address:port/
```

This should work. I am assuming you already have proxy settings for all other applications.

Answer (score 60):

The `-e` option allows you to provide commands as in wgetrc at the command line
so you do not need to change a file ...

```
wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=$proxy http://askubuntu.com
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit the `wgetrc` file located at `/etc/wgetrc`.

Use your favourite text editor, ie: `nano /etc/wgetrc` to edit it

Look for the *http_proxy* tag and remove the **#** in front of it, add the proxy server after the **=** sign, ie:

```
http_proxy=http://foo.proxy:8080
```

Then search for the *use_proxy* tag and remove the **#** in front of it, save the file.

`wget` will be then using the specified proxy server.

If you can't change system configuration with your user you can copy the current configuration to a place you can edit it, ie: `cp /etc/wgetrc ~` and use the `--config=~/wgetrc` option to force wget to use the configuration you altered instead of the global configuration.

Comment: I'm aware of this possibility, but I can't modify config files.

Comment: Think this is the only option you have with wget.

Comment: That's why I'm looking for an equivalent of wget as I indicated in the title.

Comment: I have edited the title to reflect that, it was clear on the first place what you were trying to do.

Comment: Check the last paragraph of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

From the command line only I've found success preceding the `wget` command with the `http_proxy` information without the need of using the environment variables. For example:

- `$ http_proxy=<proxy-server-ip>:<port> wget http://www.example.com/`
- `$ https_proxy=<proxy-server-ip>:<port> wget https://www.example.com/`

Answer (score 2):

Option that is not mentioned, but should be mentioned: Use environmental variables (depending your distro):

```
http_proxy=http://<proxy-server-ip>:<port>
export http_proxy
```

or simply

```
export http_proxy=http://<proxy-server-ip>:<port>
```

Same for:

```
https_proxy=http://<proxy-server-ip>:<port>
ftp_proxy=http://<proxy-server-ip>:<port>
```

You can include a username and password, if you have special characters in your password be sure to include the '-s.

```
http_proxy='http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-ip>:<port>'
```

Examples:

```
export http_proxy=http://172.16.1.100:8080
export https_proxy='http://johndoe:ABC!123@172.16.1.100:8080'
```