# Proxy authentication using wget on cygwin

Tags: proxy, wget

This question was also [posted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987794/proxy-authentication-using-wget-on-cygwin).

My institute recently installed a new proxy server for our network. I am trying to configure my `Cygwin` environment to be able to run `wget` and download data from a remote repository.

Browsing the internet I have found two different solutions to my problem, but no one of them seem to work in my case.

The first one I tried was to follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346649/how-do-i-force-wget-to-use-a-proxy-server-without-modifying-system-files), so in Cygwin:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/etc/
nano wgetrc
```

at the end of the file, I added:

```
use_proxy = on
http_proxy=http://username:password@my.proxy.ip:my.port/
https_proxy=https://username:password@my.proxy.ip:my.port/
ftp_proxy=http://username:password@my.proxy.ip:my.port/
```

(of course, using my user and password)

The second approach was what was suggested by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197904/how-do-i-use-cygwin-behind-the-corporate-firewall), so in my Cygwin environment:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@my.proxy.ip:my.port/
export https_proxy=https://username:password@my.proxy.ip:my.port/
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@my.proxy.ip:my.port/
```

in both cases, if I try to test my wget, I get the following:

```
$ wget http://www.google.com
--2020-01-30 12:12:22--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving my.proxy.ip (my.proxy.ip)... 10.1XX.XXX.XX
Connecting to my.proxy.ip (my.proxy.ip)|10.1XX.XXX.XX|:8XXX... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 407 Proxy Authentication Required
2020-01-30 12:12:22 ERROR 407: Proxy Authentication Required.
```

It looks like if my user and password are not ok, but I actually checked them on my browsers and my credentials work just fine.

Any idea on what this could be due to?

Comment: Cygwin is not Ubuntu.  This should have been posted to [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to the Unix world and I thought that there were some kinds of overlapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't edit the global configuration/startup file `wgetrc`. I would reinstall `wget` using the `cygwin` installer to get a fresh one. Instead of editing the global configuration you should provide your own by creating `.wgetrc` in your home folder. I.e.

```
nano ~/.wgetrc
```

(notice the `.` at the start of the filename, it's important)

Next I think the contents of that file should be:

```
use_proxy=on
http_proxy=http://my.proxy.ip:my.port
https_proxy=https://my.proxy.ip:my.port
ftp_proxy=http://my.proxy.ip:my.port
proxy_user=username
proxy_password=password
```

Notice that I separated the proxy user and password from the proxy URLs. Not that it should really make a difference, but you never know. I also removed the trailing `/` as that *can* make a difference, depending on how the proxy is configured.

According to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Proxies.html):

> These startup file variables allow you to override the proxy settings
>   specified by the environment.

Meaning that the configuration you put in your `.wgetrc` will override any environment variables that you `export`.

Comment: Hi @Misantorp. This fixed my problem, but only if I used `nano ~/.wgetrc`, insted of `nano $home/.wgetrc`. Thanks for helping me learning some Unix.